# How to pass listbox items from one to other form

Tags: c#, forms

I want to know how to pass listbox items from Form1 to listbox in Form2.

Suppose I have two listbox one in form1 and other in form2, and a button named button1 that calls Form2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Form2 f = new Form2(x);
         f.Show();
     }
```

where x is xmpp connection that I am passing to form2.

form2 constructor class

```
private XmppClientConnection brian;
    public Form2(XmppClientConnection x)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        brian = x;


    }
```

By using above codes I can pass the x successfully.

Now at this instance I want both x and listbox items of form1 to be passed in listbox in form2.

Comment: Can you show the constructor from form2 please? Then I can give you the right constructor.

Comment: private XmppClientConnection brian;
        public Form2(XmppClientConnection x)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            brian = x;
            
             
        }

Comment: i have edited my answer with your XmppClientConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second form create an constructor like this:

```
private XmppClientConnection brian;
public Form2(XmppClientConnect x, ListBox.ObjectCollection objectCollection){
   InitializeComponent();
   this.brian = x;
   this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(objectCollection)
}
```

And in you button click event you can then do what K. B suggested like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form2 f = new Form2(x, ListBox1.items);
     f.Show();
 }
```

XMPP connection is your connection class. I dont know how it is called now.

Comment: i am already passing a xmpp connection data named x.//private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Form2 f = new Form2(x);
             f.Show();
         }

Comment: how to send both x and listbox then?

Comment: You add another paramet to the constructor then. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Error 1 in Form2.cs Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: error in Form1.cs 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'items' and no extension method 'items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found

Comment: Type Mistake i guess. It should be Items.And i did i big type mistake also. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add a parameter in  your Form2 class  constructor

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    { 
        //here I  suppose that you have added another listbox on your form2 
        public Form2(ListBox.ObjectCollection items )
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listBox1.Items.AddRange(items)          ;}

    }
```

**Form1**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Form2 f = new Form2(listbox1.Items);
         f.Show();
     }
```

Comment: how to get data in other listbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mediator class which can set the data from form1 and you will get it on second form, for ref [clickhere](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-another-form-using-class/)

Answer (score 0):

**Form1.cs**:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form2 f = new Form2(listbox1.Items);
     f.Show();
 }
```

**Form2.cs**:

Pass the `ListBox.ObjectCollection` in parameterized constructor of `Form2` and assign it as datasource to your listbox on Form2.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{    

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(ListBox.ObjectCollection objectCollection)
    {
        InitializeComponent();           

        this.listBox1.DataSource =  objectCollection;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You can have parameterized constructor. Parameters could grow in numbers.

For example:

```
Form2 f = new Form2(sConnectionString, listbox1.Items);
f.Show();
```

Now in `Form2` you must have constructor having 2 parameters those are `string` & `ListBox.ObjectCollection`.

Example would be:

```
 public Form2(string sConnectionString, ListBox.ObjectCollection objectCollection)
    {
        InitializeComponent();           

        this.listBox1.DataSource =  objectCollection;

        //use sConnectionString here
    }
```